# How to clear h:message or rich:message value in JSF?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am developing a JSF application and I have many user forms where I use JSF validations.
I have an issue which annoys me, it will be easier to tell it with an example.

```
                    <h:panelGroup>
                    <h:selectOneRadio id="gender" value="#{registrationController.person.gender}" 
                                      required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.commonErrorBlankField}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{registrationController.genders}" />
                    </h:selectOneRadio>
                    <rich:spacer />
                    <rich:message for="gender" errorLabelClass="errorLabel">
                        <f:facet name="errorMarker">
                            <h:graphicImage value="#{msg.imageExclamation}" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </rich:message>
                </h:panelGroup>
```

Above if a radio option is not selected a required message is displayed. And when the user makes a selection I see the validation error disseapeares. Fair enough ! 
My problem is when the user navigates to next page and then by using back button of the browser comes back to this page again I can see my gender field is selected accordingly but validation error is still displayed.

Does anyone know if there is a workaround to clear the h:message field once I click the command button so validation error won't be displayed when I go back to the same page?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works. I have not tested it:

```
//idComponent is the Component whose message you want to clear, e.g. gender
void clearMessageForComponent (final String idComponent) {
        if (idComponent != null) {
            Iterator<FacesMessage> it = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessages(idComponent);
            while(it.hasNext()){
                ((FacesMessage)it.next()).setDetail("");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> It is important to understand that the browser back button won't trigger a request to the server.

that is not entirely correct, modern browsers do trigger a request if data was posted in previous stages of the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the Messages from the FacesContext won't fix your problem, since this will affect only the server side state of your application. Pushing the browser back button forces the clients browser to reload the page from the local browser cache.

It is important to understand that the browser back button won't trigger a request to the server.